# Access VBA - loop through tables based on name and insert records in another table

Tags: loops, ms-access, insert, vba

I'm looking for a way to loop through linked txt file tables in my access database with specific naming conventions (i.e. `MAProviderAcceptNewALL%`) where suffix changes and then insert all records in the tables that fit this naming convention into another table .
I'm pretty green to VBA so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the table definition list to get the table names and loop through the tables. something like:

```
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim db as Dao.Database
Set db = currentdb

For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If (VBA.Left(tdf.name, 6) = "prefix") then
        'Do your operation
    end if
Next tdf
```